# Load pipeline script from remote URL

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In Jenkins-pipeline I can load a script from the local file with

```
load 'dir/my-script.groovy'
```

Now how can I load a pipeline groovy script from a remote URL?

It would be also nice, if the loading from a remote URL could be done without allocating a node first.

Answer (score 4):

It is actually very well explained in the official [pipeline plugin documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#triggering-manual-loading).

Basically it's just :

```
git 'your-remote-repo'
load 'my-script.groovy'
```

Or if your file is not on a Git repo just use Unix `wget` in a `shell` to get your file, e.g. :

```
sh "wget example.org/myscript.groovy"
load 'myscript.groovy'
```

Also, I'm not sure what your second question means ? You can't run pipeline code outside a node, a node just defines the environment against which your Groovy code will be run, there has to be one (master by default).

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have any git repository. Just an URL, like http://example.org/myscript.groovy. Also in order to do `git ...` I have to declare a `node` first, like `node("master") {git ...}`. That is something, that I wouldn't like to do.

Comment: I just edited my post to answer your first question. As for the second, could you explain why you don't want to declare a `node` first ?

Comment: Thank you! I don't like the `node` at the beginning of the script, since it would wait for a free worker, that might not be available. Also `wget -O - example.org/myscript.groovy > myscript.groovy` is better, since otherwise wget wouldn't update the script if it changes.